# Inset only edge (of one side)

Tags: modeling

I have been looking for inset edge only (not the whole face) is it possible? Example attached.
[image]

Comment: You mean, like cutting an edge? CTRL + R? If not, you need to explain a bit more

Comment: or offset edge slide ctrl + shift + R.

Comment: Ctrl Shift R worked. Thank you. @lemon

Comment: Maybe @lemon can answer, or you can self-answer, to mark this one as solved.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by @lemon the solution is <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to *Offset Edge Slide*.